# Morphia: @PrePersist running when updating a document

Tags: morphia

I have a User entity. When I save a user document in the collection I'm hashing the password with @PrePersist but Morphia also calls @PrePersist when I try to update a document without password.

```
@PrePersist
void prePersist() {
    if (password != null) {
        System.out.println(password);
        PasswordService service = new DefaultPasswordService();
        password = service.encryptPassword(password);
    }
}
```

This is my update operation.

```
@Override
public void updateWithoutPassword(T user) {
    Query <T> query = userDAO.createQuery();
    query.and(
            query.criteria("_id").equal(user.getId())
    );
    UpdateOperations <T> updateOperations = userDAO.createUpdateOperations();
    updateOperations.set("username", user.getUsername());
    updateOperations.set("name", user.getName());
    updateOperations.set("surname", user.getSurname());
    updateOperations.set("department", user.getDepartment());
    updateOperations.set("roles", user.getRoles());
    userDAO.update(query, updateOperations);
}
```

When I call the updateWithoutPassword(), @PrePersist is running and password value is being the old password value and trying to hash the old password again. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably hash your password in setPassword() instead.  @PrePersist will always run.

Comment: Thank you it works now but according to Morphia documentation @PrePersist is running before save not update. '{{{@PrePersist}}} - Called before save, it can return a DBObject in place of an empty one.'

Comment: Did this change? I'm pretty certain that ``@prePersist`` didn't run on updates - at least before the move to GitHub (of the official version)

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I misread that.  @PrePersist always gets called when operating on the objects via save(), e.g..  UpdateOperations don't even touch the entities so there are no lifecycles to worry about.  If you're seeing your prepersist lifecycle methods run, I'd suggest putting in "new Exception().printStackTrace()" and seeing what the call tree is for that.  I'm reasonably sure it's not this method but that stacktrace should tell us.